# Поворот объекта в пространстве

Tags: математика, 3d, матрицы

У меня положение объекта в пространстве определяется углом α и вектором вращения `(x, y, z)`

Никак не соображу, как этот вектор получить для сложных поворотов?

Допустим, мне нужно повернуть объект вначале вокруг оси `y` на 90°, а потом вокруг оси `z` на 45°. Я беру и перемножаю две матрицы поворота

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как теперь из полученной матрицы получить вектор и угол?

Comment: а зачем вы этот вектор хотите извлечь из финальной матрицы ?

Comment: @ampawd Программа на вход принимает именно вектор. А матрицы это больше для понимания вопроса. Мне кажется, что проще вначале посчитать итоговую матрицу, а потом получить вектор. Матрицы они нагляднее

Comment: [тут](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToAngle/index.htm) почитайте, приведены все необходимые формулы и вывод.

Comment: @ampawd Спасибо! То, что нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за [ссылку](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToAngle/index.htm) @ampawd

Пусть, у нас есть некоторая матрица поворота

[image]

Тогда угол поворота можно вычислить по формуле

[image]

А сами компоненты вектора вращения

[image]

где

[image]

Если `K = 0`, то мы имеем симметричную матрицу. А это значит, что угол поворота 0° или 180°. При угле 0° нам ничего делать не нужно. При угле 180° вектор поворота принимает вид

[image]